# How do I find where a shape/path is open in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

Doodling around in Ai, I'm wondering how to find where my shape has a "hole" in it?

Outline mode:

[image: outline mode]

When filling that:

[image: filled]

What's a method to find where the path/shape is open, causing the area in the 2nd iteration of the circles (2nd largest) to fill in vs. following the pattern?

Thanks

Comment: A shape that has a hole in it is always a compound path, but not all compound paths have a hole. But i don't know how that is incomplete?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a compound path and it's doing this, try to change the option inside the Attributes panel. Expand it to show more options and try the **fill rule** option that isn't active right now. They are "even-odd" and "non-zero winding" rules.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try merge the whole graphic?
Maybe can work. Usually show an error when you applied a pathfinder effect.

Normal
[image]
Outline
[image]
Merge with pathfinder
[image]

Good luck!