# Illustrator filling color outside boundary

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill, pen-tool

I have this figure on illustrator:
[image]

But when I try to fill color, the color overflows outside the boundary:

[image]

A question mark appears in the fill tool as well.

How will I fix this?

Comment: Is your shape closed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find where a shape/path is open in Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79269/how-do-i-find-where-a-shape-path-is-open-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 1):

Your shape is actually a bunch of open paths. To fix it you can select the ends of the open paths and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the paths. I've circled (I think) the end points of the open paths in the following image; just use the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) to select the paths I've circled and join, repeat for each area I've circled.

[image]

In future, if you're drawing with the Pen Tool and want to *continue* an existing path rather than drawing a new one you need to start by clicking on the end point of the path you want to continue (The Pen Tool's cursor will have a slash ( / ) next to it when you hover the existing paths end point). Or you can join the paths after the fact as I described.